# I can't tune up material drawer 6.0.2 in android studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, materialdrawer

I can't tune up material drawer 6.0.2 from https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vlado.navigationsandfragments"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation("com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.2@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }

    //required support lib modules
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.supportLib}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${versions.supportLib}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${versions.supportLib}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${versions.supportLib}"
}
```

Exception:Error:(38, 0) Could not get unknown property 'versions' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

I think the problem is in "required support lib modules" ,but if I delete them , the application have no error and doesn't work.

Comment: Just guessing (I'm no gradle expert) but maybe you could exchange `${versions.supportLib}` for `26.1.0`

Comment: yes, this is problem . Thank you :)

Comment: how do you solved this problem-@Vladislav Penchev

Comment: @creativecoder simply change that ${versions.supportLib} with the latest release number and done